# Pandas groupby custom groups

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'B': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']})
print(df)

   A  B
0  1  a
1  2  a
2  3  b
3  4  b
4  5  c
5  6  c
```

How can I group by col `B` such that the groups are `a`, `a OR b` and `a OR b OR c`, rather than just `a`, `b` and `c`? For the sake of the example, let's say that I want to aggregate the results by `'sum'`. I would then end up with:

```
              A
a             3
a OR b        10 
a OR b OR c   21
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it really depends on the function you want to use.
I can think of a trick with [`DataFrame.expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) for example if you want to calculate the **sum**.The idea is that we can take advantage of the expansion and then only take into account the rows where entire groups have been selected with [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)

```
df.expanding().sum().where(df['B'].ne(df['B'].shift(-1)))
      A
0   NaN
1   3.0
2   NaN
3  10.0
4   NaN
5  21.0
```

---

```
df.expanding().sum().where(df['B'].ne(df['B'].shift(-1))).loc[lambda x: x.A.notna()]

      A
1   3.0
3  10.0
5  21.0
```

**UPDATED**

We can also use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`DataFrame.expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html)

```
df.groupby('B').sum().expanding().sum()
```

**To get the expected output:**

```
new_df = (df.groupby('B').sum().expanding().sum()
            .reset_index()
            .assign(B = lambda x: x.B.add(' or ').cumsum()
                                  .str.rstrip(' or '))
            .set_index('B') )
print(new_df)
                A
B                
a             3.0
a or b       10.0
a or b or c  21.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice suggestion. However, I am more interested in a 'typical' `groupby`output. I have updated the question with an example output.